# Javascript: Validate for only alpha and space

Tags: javascript, html, function, validation, space

I have this function which I use to validate for letters only when a user inputs something in a textbox.
I just realized it does not accept spaces. How would I fix this? Just add the charCode value to the equation?

```
function isLetter2(evt) {
       evt = (evt) ? evt : event;
       var charCode = (evt.charCode) ? evt.charCode : ((evt.keyCode) ? evt.keyCode :
          ((evt.which) ? evt.which : 0));
       if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 65 || charCode > 90) &&
          (charCode < 97 || charCode > 122)) {
          return false;
       }
       return true;
     }
```

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out? Seems like an easy test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A space is charcode 32 (hexadecimal 20), so just add this line before your first if statement.

```
if (charCode == 32) return true;
```

followed by your original if statement. (No additional else statement is needed between them since the function will now stop and return true as soon as a space is detected.)

update: your original if statement can be simplified by De Morgan's laws to <= 31 or (inclusively between 65 and 90) or (inclusively between 97 and 122). So it would also work fine just to change your first > 31 to be > 32 since its negation would be <= 32 and result in returning of true, thus allowing a space to be typed. But I am not sure why you would want to allow all of the other characters less than 32 to be typed... that includes a lot of weird stuff. Maybe you should change your code to be like this:

```
if (charCode == 32 ||
   (charCode >= 65 && charCode <= 90) ||
   (charCode >= 97 && charCode <= 122))
     return true;
else return false;
```

In fact, the result of all those comparisons is itself equal to the value true or the value false, and so you can completely eliminate the if/else statements and just say:

```
return charCode == 32 || (charCode >= 65 && charCode <= 90) || (charCode >= 97 && charCode <= 122);
```